# How to run a sql within a field in the Pentaho?

Tags: sql, pentaho

I have a table with a 'query' field containing a select sql and another 'parameters' field containing the sql parameters. I have already merged these two fields into a new field containing a correct select sql statement. Now I need to execute this new field containing select sql, get the return from select (the output fields) and generate an excel file.

Answer (score 0):

In your transformation, you can use the [Execute row SQL script](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Execute+row+SQL+script) (under scripting), which does exactly what you want, executing the SQL contained in the selected input field for each row passed to the step.

Please do consider if that's **really** what you want. It works fine for a small set or complicated logic, but is very inefficient compared to batch inserts and updates.

If your SQL statements do look like "INSERT [some data]" and you have many rows to process, consider splitting the streams with filter steps and applying calculations or constants to each case to set the values correctly, then directing all to a table output step.

Comment: My field contains a select sql statement, and I need the output fields of select sql to generate an excel file.

Comment: What is different in each of the select queries?

Comment: I'll explain better.
I have a table with a 'query' field containing a select sql and another 'parameters' field containing the sql parameters. I have already merged these two fields into a new field containing a correct select sql statement. Now I need to execute this new field containing select sql, get the return from select (the output fields) and generate an excel file.